# Theoretical integral curve - fields lemma proof

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**I need help or a thorough proof on understanding the following theoretical lemma regarding integral curves and fields. This is a part of the "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations with Applications - Zachmanoglou"**.

First of all, where to begin from for proving part (a) of the lemma-protasis ?

Secondly, I can't comprehend part (b).

> Let $C$ be an integral curve of the vector field $V = (P,Q,R)$ and suppose that $C$ is given parametrically by the equations 
>   $$x=x(t), \; \; y = y(t), \; \; z = z(t) \; ; \; t \in I$$
>   where the functions $x(t), y(t)$ and $z(t)$  are in $C^1(I)$ and the tangent vector 
>   $$T(t) = \bigg(\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{dt},\frac{\mathrm{d}y(t)}{dt}, \frac{\mathrm{d}z(t)}{dt}\bigg)$$
>   never vanishes for $t \in I$.
>
> (a) Show that there exists a function $μ(t)$ in $C^1(I)$ such that for every $t \in I$ it is :
>   $$μ(t) \neq 0 \; \; \text{and} \; \; V(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = μ(t)T(t)$$
>
> (b) Let $t = τ(t)$ be a solution of the differential equation
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}τ}=μ(t)$$
>   where $τ$ varies over some interval $I'$ as $t$ varies over $I$. Set
>   $$\bar{x}(τ)=x(t(τ)), \; \bar{y}(τ)=y(t(τ)), \; \bar{z}(τ)=\bar{z}(t(τ))$$
>   Show that in terms of the new parametric representation 
>   $$x = \bar{x}(τ), \; \; y = \bar{y}(τ), \; \; z = \bar{z}(τ) \; ; \; t \in I'$$
>   the curve $C$ is a solution of the system of equations associated with $V$
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}τ}=P, \; \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}τ}=Q, \; \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}τ}=R$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the definition of integral curve that comes to mind requires that $(dx/dt,dy/dt,dz/dt) = V(x,y,z)$.  If this is the definition you're using, shouldn't $\mu=1$?